# How to subtract Nth rows from a certain row within a column multiple times

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, loops, for-loop

I want to be able to subtract a specific number of rows from another specific set of rows multiple times. I assume I would do this with a for loop but I can't figure out how exactly to do this.

For example I would like to subtract the yields from the treatment group from the control within the same field. Every 6 rows I would like to subtract the 4-6th row from the 1-3rd rows over and over again

This is the what I have thus far:

`dfArray = df ['Crop_Yield'].to_numpy()`

```
  `for i in range(len(dfArray('Crop_Yield') //6):`
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out with this. Sorry if something like this has been asked before, I tired looking but didn't find anything similar.

Below is an example of the table.

| Treatment | Field | Crop_Yield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control | 1 Top | 14 |
| Control | 2 Top | 18 |
| Control | 3 Top | 16 |
| Fert A | 1 Bottom | 12 |
| Fert A | 2 Bottom | 17 |
| Fert A | 3 Bottom | 15 |
| Control | 4 Top | 10 |
| Control | 5 Top | 13 |
| Control | 6 Top | 15 |
| Fert B | 4 Bottom | 17 |
| Fert B | 5 Bottom | 13 |
| Fert B | 6 Bottom | 18 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly:

```py
for i in range(len(df) // 6):
    df.loc[i * 6 : i * 6 + 2, "Crop_Yield"] -= df.loc[i * 6 + 3 : i * 6 + 5, "Crop_Yield"].to_numpy()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Treatment     Field  Crop_Yield
0    Control     1 Top           2
1    Control     2 Top           1
2    Control     3 Top           1
3     Fert A  1 Bottom          12
4     Fert A  2 Bottom          17
5     Fert A  3 Bottom          15
6    Control     4 Top          -7
7    Control     5 Top           0
8    Control     6 Top          -3
9     Fert B  4 Bottom          17
10    Fert B  5 Bottom          13
11    Fert B  6 Bottom          18
```

Comment: Yes, this is subtracting the correct rows! I forgot to add that I would like to make a new column or dataframe with the answers. How would I go about doing that part?